# PHP-GD imagejpeg unable to open

Tags: php, gd

When trying to save a thumbnail made with GD

```
imagejpeg($tnImage, "../../img/thumbs/".$maxWidth."x".$maxHeight."_".$filename);
```

I am getting the following error:

**Warning**: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '../../img/thumbs/80x80_55865-drops.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in **/home/user/workspace/stewart/server-side/libImg.php**

/home/user/workspace/img/thumbs has its permissions set to 0x777.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: It can't find the file, but that shouldn't be a problem, because the imagejpeg function should create it if it doesn't exist. What version of GD are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you running the file from?  If it's from the `server-side` directory then I think you're missing a "../"

Try this:

```
var_dump(realpath("../../img/thumbs/".$maxWidth."x".$maxHeight."_".$filename));
```

Comment: var_dump(realpath("../../img/thumbs")); returns bool(false).

Comment: From php.net:
realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.

Check the path, try with the absolute path maybe.

Comment: I'm getting a false response on this: http://mydomain.com/wpdev/wp-content/uploads/bool(false). I have a feeling it's not saving my uploaded image to the server anywhere. I'll try doing just a straight upload instead of resizing for now and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
/home/user/workspace/stewart/server-side/
```

the directory

```
../../img/thumbs/
```

would equate to

```
 /home/user/workspace/img/thumbs/
```

so you need

```
../../../img/thumbs/
```

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake when writing the question:
/home/user/workspace/img/thumbs has its permissions set to 0x777.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is providing the `imagejpeg` with the full path to the file.

So you can have in `config.php` something like

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH',  dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then in your functions.php call imagejpeg like this:

```
@imagejpeg($image, APPLICATION_PATH . '/uploads/myfile.jpg', $quality);
```