# Error with my SLIDER: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg] -- So close to a solution, but need an extra push

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting the following error on my site here:

http://www.cdiwa.com.au

> **Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home1/cdiwa/public_html//wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Hero-Shot-IS_0905_HWE_02_700x467-279660_640x304.jpg'
>   for writing: Permission denied in
>   /home1/cdiwa/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 455**

I've looked at the solution proposed here:

*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757008/php-gd-imagejpeg-unable-to-open*

however, I am struggling to find exactly how to modify the 'realpath' as outlined below:

**

> var_dump(realpath("../../img/thumbs/".$maxWidth."x".$maxHeight."_".$filename));

**

The issue can be pined to this call in my home.php:

```
        <?php if ( get_option('feather_featured') == 'on' && is_home() ) get_template_part('includes/featured'); ?>
```

I've also tried reseting permissions.

It is also worth pointing out the slider is working here:
http://www.cdiwa.com.au/about-us/

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Thanks for your time.
Brendan

Comment: What are the file permissions for that directory/file and what user:group owns them?

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy and paste the error? If so you have something adding a / where it isn't needed. Notice this part:
/public_html//wp-content/