# php file resized and upload into server folder

Tags: php, mysql

Local image file rezised and uploaded successfully after put into the server it's coming up with the following error:

> Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'photo/Desert.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in D:\hosting\9393253\html\dev\

Comment: seems like you have got wrong path to the file... show your code

Comment: Sorry, we can't guess what your source code is.

Comment: Hello ! It seem you have missed any type of real pathing to your file , please can you post more code that we can be more in image to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked earlier on stackoverflow.I think its path issue and this link 
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757008/php-gd-imagejpeg-unable-to-open)

will help you out.